# What is a standard way to add tf.placeholder for test/validation data with queue runners

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a training model that takes all training data and creates a queue:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (N, steps, size), name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (N, out_size), name='y')
var_x = tf.Variable(x, trainable=False, collections=[])
var_y = tf.Variable(y, trainable=False, collections=[])
x_queue, y_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([var_x, var_y], 
                                                 num_epochs=10, shuffle=True)
x_batch, y_batch = tf.train.batch([x_queue, y_queue], batch_size=batch_size)

...

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(var_x, feed_dict={x: X})
   sess.run(var_y, feed_dict={y: Y})
   coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

...
```

This network works fine and I am able to train it. 
In this network I'd like to add a new placeholder that takes my test data:

```
x_test = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, steps, size), name='x_test')
```

And I'd like to use `tf.cond` to control which placeholder gets fed:

```
rnn_inputs = tf.cond(is_train, lambda: x, lambda: x_test)
```

However, a lot of posts say using `tf.cond` is not efficient. In addition, using a new placeholder for test/validation data is a problem since tensorflow throws an error asking me to feed data into it even if I am trying to train the model.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient is to use iterators to feed your data. You can create a handle to specify whether to feed from the train or validation dataset. Here is an example from https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets. I have found this method effective

```
# Define training and validation datasets with the same structure.
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(
    lambda x: x + tf.random_uniform([], -10, 10, tf.int64)).repeat()
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(50)

# A feedable iterator is defined by a handle placeholder and its structure. We
# could use the output_types and output_shapes properties of either
# training_dataset or validation_dataset here, because they have
# identical structure.
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
    handle, training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# You can use feedable iterators with a variety of different kinds of iterator
# (such as one-shot and initializable iterators).
training_iterator = training_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
validation_iterator = validation_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

# The Iterator.string_handle() method returns a tensor that can be evaluated
# and used to feed the handle placeholder.
training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())

# Loop forever, alternating between training and validation.
while True:
  # Run 200 steps using the training dataset. Note that the training dataset is
  # infinite, and we resume from where we left off in the previous `while` loop
  # iteration.
  for _ in range(200):
    sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})

  # Run one pass over the validation dataset.
  sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)
  for _ in range(50):
    sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
```